# Javascript - when user tries to navigate away from page in address bar, catch and navigate back

Tags: javascript, redirect, onbeforeunload

Yes - I've done research (both here and elsewhere) on onbeforeunload as well as a few other things.  What I want is a Javascript means to accomplish the following user story...
User is on a page (where they need to fill in a text box, or click Cancel).  They try to navigate away from the page (via the address bar) without providing a value or clicking cancel.  Javascript recognizes that they have not done the text box or Cancel, and silently reroutes them back to the original page (instead of what they put in the address bar).  I may present them with a message box, but for now want it to work silently.

I feel like it would need to be done client side (once the server gets involved, its too late).

I'm not a Javascript expert by any means.

How best to accomplish this?  Thanks.

I tried using onbeforeunload.  Unfortunately, it does not seem to provide a lot of latitude in the handler (static message, etc.)

Comment: In the general case, you cannot prevent a user from navigating away from your page. They might for example unplug their computer. It's their browser, after all.

Comment: Simple answer here, you can't.   Can you image not so nice websites stopping you navigating were you wanted to go.

Comment: People do things like hook up "blur" handlers for the page to pop up an annoying thing that tries to get you to stick around. And there's the "beforeunload" handler you mentioned. So there are ways you can nudge the user to stick around, but ultimately they make the decision.

Comment: Had a feeling that might be the case.  I'll have to do something server-side when trying to nav within my site and redirect.  Outside my site, they're free to go.